# How do I update the version number in a Plone add-on?

Tags: plone, plone-3.x

Version and installation profile numbering for Plone add-ons has been changing and this is very confusing. What worked in one version of Plone will not necessarily work in other places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gaer Baekholt pointed me to this page: http://plone.org/documentation/how-to/version-numbers-in-cmfquickinstaller